# Excel & VBA: 'If value is less than 1' condition being triggered by a value that is exactly 1

Tags: vba, excel

I've encountered a baffling behaviour in Excel VBA that I'm trying to understand and wondered if anyone can point me in the direction of the explanation please?

Background - I've inherited a reporting tool that is used to calculate whether there is enough remaining allowance of holiday each day to allow an additional holiday to be taken. I found that it is behaving unexpectedly when the remaining allowance is exactly '1'.

Below was the VBA as it already existed (the values of the variables in the real file are set by other queries but I've set them manually here in order to replicate the issue). With this code, the message box is triggered even though the result of (Total * Allowance) - Taken is exactly 1 and the 'If' condition should only be met by values **less than 1**

```
Dim Total As Double
Dim Allowance As Double
Dim Taken As Double

Total = 20
Allowance = 0.15
Taken = 2

If (Total * Allowance) - Taken < 1 Then
    MsgBox "Not Enough Allowance Remaining"
End If
```

I tried changing the code to the below and found that when 'remaining' is declared as 'double' datatype, the same issue occurs. However if I change the datatype of 'remaining' to 'single', the code behaves as expected and the message box is not displayed:

```
Dim Total As Double
Dim Allowance As Double
Dim Taken As Double
Dim Remaining As Double

Total = 20
Allowance = 0.15
Taken = 2
Remaining = (Total * Allowance) - Taken

If Remaining < 1 Then
     MsgBox "Not Enough Allowance Remaining"
End If
```

I reasoned it must be something to do with the way Excel / VBA handles the value '1' in different data types and some searching turned up the articles below but I'm unsure if I'm on the right track or am missing a simpler answer - any ideas please?

[Article 1](https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2012/01/23/stupid-float-tricks-2/)
[Article 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeric_precision_in_Microsoft_Excel)

Thanks

Comment: This isn't necessarily an answer, but I'm able to replicate your issue, and using `Single` results in `Remaining` being `1.00000011920928` which is why it works.  Still unsure why `Double` making it = `1` isn't working?

Comment: I'm puzzled by this as well. Seems like the alternative formulation of your specific problem into "If Total * Allowance < 1 + Taken Then" seems to do the trick, but I have no idea why

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple rounding problem.  This works:

```
Sub dural()
Dim Total As Double
Dim Allowance As Double
Dim Taken As Double

Total = 20
Allowance = 0.15
Taken = 2
If ((Total * Allowance) - Taken) < 0.999999 Then
    MsgBox "Not Enough Allowance Remaining"
End If
End Sub
```

Because the floating point arithmetic  does not yield exactly **1**
For example:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim Total As Double
    Dim Allowance As Double
    Dim Taken As Double

    Total = 20
    Allowance = 0.15
    Taken = 2
    If (Total * Allowance) - Taken < 0.999999 Then
        MsgBox "Not Enough Allowance Remaining"
    End If

    MsgBox 1 - ((Total * Allowance) - Taken)

End Sub
```

Produces:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is a known and well documented "issue" with Excel. As summarized here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeric_precision_in_Microsoft_Excel

"As with other spreadsheets, Microsoft Excel works only to limited accuracy because it retains only a certain number of figures to describe numbers (it has limited precision). [...] Although Excel can display 30 decimal places, its precision for a specified number is confined to 15 significant figures, and calculations may have an accuracy that is even less due to three issues: round off, truncation, and binary storage."

So, if you change your second code snippet to the following:

```
Dim Total As Double
Dim Allowance As Double
Dim Taken As Double
Dim Remaining As Double

Total = 20
Allowance = 0.15
Taken = 2
Remaining = (Total * Allowance) - Taken

If Remaining < 1 Then
     MsgBox 1 - Remaining
End If
```

You will come to realize that the inaccuracy starts (exactly as described above) at the 15th decimal place. For more samples and a more elaborate analysis you might also want to have a look at the following post: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/rounding.htm

Answer (score 0):

You are absolutely correct that the data types are the issue.

The problem is (basically) that `Double` can't represent certain numbers accurately (though they can do it very precisely), because of the peculiarities of how floating point types encode the numbers they represent (basically: as a number raised to a power).

If you're dealing with decimal data, or currency data, **you're probably best off using a fixed precision type,** like `Currency`, rather than `Double`, which is going to provide a guaranteed level of precision (currency is both precise and accurate to 4 decimal places).

If you need greater precision than 4 decimal places, using a `Variant` is probably your best bet, and coercing it to a decimal:

```
Dim Total As Variant
Dim Allowance As Variant
Dim Taken As Variant

Total = CDec(20)
Allowance = CDec(0.15)
Taken = CDec(2)

If (Total * Allowance) - Taken < 1 Then
    MsgBox "Not Enough Allowance Remaining"
End If
```

(The coercion will probably happen implicitly, but if you're paranoid, `CDec()` will force it.)